# How long does it take to clear the first billing charge for my google app engine app?

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, quota

I've made an app in order to send large mailings. Google enforces a 100 recipient a day maximum as I read on the [quota page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Mail):

> 100 messages daily until first charge cleared; 20,000 messages per day thereafter

After deploying the app I've intentionally maxed out the 100 recipient limit, which adds a charge to my billing account of $0.01 This is also shown in my [billing history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNmpW.png).

However I've also set a weekly budget of $2.10 The one time charged associated with this budget has been made succesfully according to my Google Wallet. Looking at my current quota's it seems it's still limited to 100 even after waiting for 24 hours for my quota's to reset. Has anybody had the same problem? I don't know what to do next or how to interpret the "leave grace period" mentioned in my billing history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were a new customer, you would have to wait one week, but you have already cleared a charge so you should be able to exceed the 100 user quota immediately. You may want to try to send mail and see if you get quota exceeded exceptions.

The "Leave Grace Period" messages mean that [a charge previously failed putting you in the Grace Period](https://developers.google.com/appengine/kb/billing#grace). You then later successfully charged your credit card and left the Grace Period.

App Engine has [announced that it will shortly be changing its billing system](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2013/03/app-engine-176-released.html). So this answer will be outdated within a few weeks.

Comment: The first week has already passed since the App has been running from 2013-03-06 13:54:56. I just ran another 120 e-mails and the App starts returning "over quote" errors after the 100th e-mail just like last time adding a billable $0.01 to my overview.

Comment: I ended up contacting a Google App engine representative who had to manually solve my problem.

Comment: @Elicit how did you reach this representative? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @jirungaray  google-cloud-billing-support@google.com